# Angular 2: "Unknown Provider: $$angularInjectorProvider" when unit testing with an `UpgradeModule` downgraded service

Tags: angularjs

Our app currently has some 4,500+ existing Angular 1 tests. We're now incorporating Angular 2 using `UpgradeModule` to downgrade an Angular 2 service, which is used from our app's run() method. This causes all tests to fail with a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider $$angularInjectorProvider` error.

I created a plnkr to demonstrate this issue (http://plnkr.co/edit/XuMYBr9xInqq18Kr6EAs?p=preview).

Basically the Angular 1 module looks like this:

```
// angular1.module.ts

angular.module( 'testApp' )
    .run( [ 'Angular2Service', Angular2Service => {  // injecting downgraded service
        Angular2Service.showTestMessage();
    } ] );
```

Where `Angular2Service` is downgraded with:

```
// app.module.ts

angular.module( 'testApp' )
    .factory( 'Angular2Service', downgradeInjectable( Angular2Service ) );


@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, UpgradeModule ],
    providers : [ Angular2Service ]
})
export class AppModule {
    ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

Originally with this so far, I was getting an Unknown Provider error for `'Angular2Service'` itself when the tests executed, so I added a `beforeEach()` that compiles everything in `AppModule`:

```
beforeEach( async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
        imports : [ AppModule ]
    } )
        .compileComponents();
} ) );
```

And that's where I'm at with the `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown Provider $$angularInjectorProvider` error.

The test itself that is executing is purely an Angular 1 test, which passes if I don't inject `Angular2Service` into the run() method:

```
describe( 'testComponent', () => {
    var $compile,
        $scope;

    beforeEach( module( 'testApp' ) );

    beforeEach( inject( $injector => {
        $compile = $injector.get( '$compile' );
        $scope = $injector.get( '$rootScope' ).$new();
    } ) );


    it( 'should show the text "Test Component" in the DOM', () => {
        var element = $compile( '<test-component></test-component>' )( $scope );
        $scope.$apply();

        expect( element[ 0 ].innerHTML ).toBe( 'Test Component' );
    } );

} );
```

I'm hoping that this can be fixed so that all of our pure Angular 1 tests can continue to work unchanged, but I can update them too if need be. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

http://plnkr.co/edit/XuMYBr9xInqq18Kr6EAs?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem and came with a solution. It is not the best to be done, but it just solves the problem in the migration phase.

I'm sure that you use `upgrade-static.umd.js` dist file rather than `upgrade.umd.js`. The static one is intended to be used with ngc AoT compilation which we should use in production apps. If you dig into its code you can easily figure it defines new angularjs module named `$$UpgradeModule` which registers a value provider named `$$angularInjector` (the one in the error above) - this `$$angularInjector` thing is responsible for injecting Angular modules into angularjs.

## The problem

Your old angularjs test don't initiate `$$UpgradeModule` so its providers are not injectable. Note that `angular-mocks` (which defines both global `module` and `inject` fns) do some patches for jasmine and mocka to provide some injection isolation between suites.

## The solution

You simply need to call `module('$$UpgradeModule')` in the first beforeEach every time you will test a code that will inject (directly or indirectly) the downgraded provider.

However, this is not that simple :). Actually `$$UpgradeModule` is declared in `UpgradeModule.boorstrap` function. which means you need to bootstrap the whole app (both angularjs and Angular) before any test (or in more strict form - bootstrap the root module). This is not nice because we want to test modules and providers in complete isolation.

## Another solution

An alternative may be to use the `UpgradeAdapter` defined in `upgrade.umd.js`. Honestly, I didn't try it - but from the code it seems it can initiate just the modules that we want without bootstrapping the whole app. But I think we may need to redo downgrades in tests using `UpgradeAdapter` methods to have things work.

---

## EDIT

### Example:

To bootstrap, you need to import your app module is SystemJs before     importing test files. So ur `karma-stest-shim.js` will contain something like that

```
System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(importSystemJsExtras)
  .then(importApp)
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

function importApp() {
    return Promise.all(
        [
            System.import('app'),
        ]
    )
}
```

This will do the normal bootstrap for the both versions and make `$$upgradeModule` defined.

Then in any test that will inject the downgraded provider

```
beforeEach(function () {
    // the ng1 module for the downgraded provider 
    module('services');
    // the trick is here
    module('$$UpgradeModule');
});
```

Comment: Can't get the `$$UpgradeModule` injected. How can I do this? Something in the `karma-test-shim.js`?

Comment: @michaelK no it is not related to `karam-test-shim.js`. what is the error u got when trying to inject `module('$$UpgradeModule')` in the tests?

Comment: Inserted code:
```beforeEach(module('$$UpgradeModule'));```
got this error:
```Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $$UpgradeModule due to:
[1]  Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$$UpgradeModule' is not available!```

Comment: You wrote the whole app has to be bootstraped. How to do it with karma?

Comment: beforeEach call should be `beforeEach(function(){module('$$UpgradeModule')})`. I will edit the answer and add some code samples.

Comment: I tried bootstrapping my app inside the karma shim. However, this made `angular.mock.module()` stop working: tests that were supposed to mock out functionality instead loaded the real implementation, and all my tests broke.

Comment: Guys, @YasserRabee, did you manage to get this working? How to bootstrap the root module before any test?

Actually, I have `getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,platformBrowserDynamicTesting())` in my test.ts

And when I'm trying to do the `angular.mock.module('$$UpgradeModule')` I get `Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '$$UpgradeModule' is not available!`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just mock out the service being downgraded. When you have in your angular part something like this:

```
angular.module('ng1module')
  ).factory('service', downgradeInjectable(MyService) as any);
```

then you can mock the service with the `$provide`-syntax as follows:

```
module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('service',{});
})
```